# Move the s3 bucket to other aws server

Tags: amazon-s3, server

I have created a AWS s3 buckets and here uploaded many of images but now i want to move all images to other AWS s3 buckets.

so can we direct copy buckets or link to other AWS server.

Please provide suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) S3 modules `cp` ( copy ) command to copy files from bucket to bucket:

```
aws s3 cp S3://mybucket/file.jpg S3://anotherbucket/file.jpg
```

See [cp command documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html).

Comment: FYI, the traffic will flow directly between buckets. It does not download or upload the files. The buckets can also be in different regions.